# Jquery multiple plus/minus script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms on a page and also multiple input boxes with plus/minus signs.

I'm having trouble to get those input boxes to work seperately. Probably because of some wrong/same id's or something like that or maybe a wrong setup of my code. The thing is I can't find my error in the code and I don't get any errors in my console.

What I have:

```
        function quantity_change(way, id){

          quantity = $('#product_amount_'+id).val();
          if(way=='up'){
            quantity++;
              } else {
              quantity--;
          }
          if(quantity<1){
            quantity = 1;
          }
          if(quantity>10){
            quantity = 10;
          }
          $('#product_amount_'+id).val(quantity);

        }
```

And my html:

```
//row 1
 <div class="amount"><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" id="product_amount_1234"/></div>
  <div class="change" data-id="1234">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="quantity_change('up');" title="+" class="up">+</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="quantity_change('down');" title="-" class="down">-</a>
 </div>

//row 2
 <div class="amount"><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" id="product_amount_4321"/></div>
  <div class="change" data-id="4321">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="quantity_change('up');" title="+" class="up">+</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="quantity_change('down');" title="-" class="down">-</a>
 </div>
```

I thought something like this would do the trick but it doesn't :(

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.change a').click(function(){
              var id = $(this).find('.change').data('id');
              quantity_change(id)
            });
           });
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `closest()` method to get access to the parent div with class `change`, then you can read the data attribute id's value.

```
var id = $(this).closest('.change').data('id');
alert(id);
```

Since you are already binding the click event using unobutrusive javascript, you do not need the `onclick` code in your HTML markup.

Also your `quantity_change` method takes 2 parameters and using both, but you are passing only one. You may keep the value of `way` in HTML 5 data attributes on the anchor tag and read from that and pass that to your method.

```
<div class="change" data-id="1234">
    <a href="#" data-way="up" title="+" class="up">+</a>
    <a href="#" data-way="down" title="-" class="down">-</a>
 </div>
```

So the corrected js code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('.change a').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var _this=$(this);

          var id = _this.closest('.change').data('id');
          var way= _this.data("way");

          quantity_change(way,id)
     });

 });
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/cageju/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.